# Best implementation of REAL backpressure in RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming

Well, backpressure in RxJava is not real backpressure, but only ignoring some sets of elements.

But what if I cannot loose any elements and I need to slow emition somehow?

RxJava cannot affect element emition, so developer needs to implement it by himself. But how?

The simpliest way comes to mind is to use some counter with incrementing on emition and decrementing on finishing.

Like that:

```
public static void sleep(int ms) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    Scheduler sA = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    Scheduler sB = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));

    Observable.create(s -> {
        while (!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
            if (counter.get() < 100) {
                s.onNext(Math.random());
                counter.incrementAndGet();
            } else {
                sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(sA)
            .flatMap(r ->
                    Observable.just(r)
                            .subscribeOn(sB)
                            .doOnNext(x -> sleep(1000))
                            .doOnNext(x -> counter.decrementAndGet())
            )
            .subscribe();
}
```

But I think this way is very poor. Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3):

> Well, backpressure in RxJava is not real backpressure

RxJava's backpressure implementation is a non-blocking cooperation between subsequent producers and consumers through a request channel. The consumer asks for some amount of elements via `request()` and the producers creates/generates/emits at most that amount of items via `onNext`, sometimes with delays between `onNext`s.

> but only ignoring some sets of elements.

This happens only when you explicitly tell RxJava to drop any overflow.

> RxJava cannot affect element emition, so developer needs to implement it by himself. But how?

Using `Observable.create` requires advanced knowledge of how non-blocking backpressure can be implemented and practically it is not recommended to library users. RxJava has plenty of ways to give you backpressure-enabled flows without complications:

```
Observable.range(1, 100)
.map(v -> Math.random())
.subscribeOn(sA)
.flatMap(v ->
    Observable.just(v).subscribeOn(sB)
    .doOnNext(x -> sleep(1000))
)
.subscribe();
```

or

```
Observable.create(SyncOnSubscribe.createStateless(
    o -> o.onNext(Math.random())
)
.subscribeOn(sA)
...
```

Comment: I've read the topic about backpressure. And I'm asking for the way to slow down element emition for my example. Say I'm reading records from database by cursor and I need to slowdown it, cause system processes records slower then producer emits them.

Comment: That is pull based and you pull as fast as the downstream can consume it.

Answer (score -1):

As you noted yourself, this actually has nothing to do with RxJava.
If you must process all events eventually, but you want to do that at your own pace, use queues:

```
    ExecutorService emiter = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ScheduledExecutorService workers = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
    BlockingQueue<String> events = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();


    emiter.submit(() -> {
       System.out.println("I'll send 100 events as fast as I can");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                events.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    workers.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            () -> {
                String result = null;
                try {
                    result = events.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println(String.format("I don't care, got %s only now", result));
            }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    );
```

Comment: Queue is not backpressure. The point of backpressure is to signal to the producer to slow down the emission. It might not be always possible, but in a vast majority of cases, it is. This is why explicit backpressure is in the new Reactive Streams specification in JDK9. https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm